# This question needs reopening, please

Tags: discussion, reopen

**Edit note:** Now reopened. Thank you everyone!

---

This question here:

- ['She was shot by police yesterday' or 'She was shot yesterday by police'](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/116095/she-was-shot-by-police-yesterday-or-she-was-shot-yesterday-by-police)

was closed as a duplicate of this question here:

- [Where is the correct place to place adverbs in sentences?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/8870/where-is-the-correct-place-to-place-adverbs-in-sentences)

The first one is about Adjuncts/Adverbials and the second is about adverbs. However, Adjuncts/Adverbials on the one hand and adverbs on the other are very different things. The first is a grammatical relation and the second is a part of speech (the examples in the first question do not contain any adverbs). More importantly, the second question asks about a very specific type of adverb, focussing adverbs. Although these can function as Adjuncts/Adverbials, these single word items have a completely different distribution from temporal, locative or agentive Adjuncts/Adverbials. Totally and utterly different.

If the Original Poster in the first question tried to use their noun phrase and preposition phrase adjuncts in the same way as the focussing adverbs discussed in the second question then they would have very big problems, because they would come up with sentences such as:

- I yesterday slept.
- I was by the police arrested.

This is not a very good outcome for the Original Poster in the first question, or for any readers who visit the site.

Furthermore we are actively cultivating the wildly inaccurate idea that adverbials are adverbs - they are not!

Can readers here please vote reopen the Original Question (after which it could be linked to a genuine duplicate - if there is one).